# Is z-score normalization with hard caps reasonable?

Tags: normalization, autoencoders

I am currently trying to train an variational autoencoder that is implemented in TensorFlow. I have a training set with around 25 000 samples which I normalize by using the formula

[image: norm]

where the $i$ denotes the i-th training sample. This maps the values to area around 0. Because this is an autoencoder, the training set contains only "good" data, e.g. so that it is able to identify anomalies via the reconstruction error. For this good data, all values are close to 0 (e.g. 0.83).

Now for testing, I got myself a set of around 5 000 additional samples that DO contain anomalies (e.g. very big values) that get normalized with the mean and standard deviation of the training set. The NORMALIZED value for one of those anomalies is 2484, for example. If I give this value to my autoencoder, it produces NaNs for the reconstructed input because seemingly those values become very large within the net. While this is good for detecting anomalies, I would still like to have a large numerical value instead of a NaN.

The first solution that came to my mind was to restrict the range that those normalized values could take. For instance, all normalized values equal to or greater than 20 are automatically set to 20.

**Question:** is using those hard caps a reasonable way to produce numerical values? Or is there a way to deal with such values?

Comment: I do not understand why is it that an autoencoder should train only on "good" data? what do you call good data? as I understand, your training data should represent the distribution of all data from that form, meaning it should hold enough examples to show how all targeted data  looks like. the data inputed to your learning algorithm (any learning algorithm!) at the testing phase should be from that same distribution, hence, normalized as well.

Comment: @havakok: The task of the autoencoder is to detect anomalies in the data. I do not know how these anomalies will look like. Therefore, I'm left with data that represents a normal system state. That is what I called "good data" (e.g. non-anomaly data). The test data is also from the same distribution, but these anomalies can be seen as a kind of outlier that I want to detect.

Comment: You are trying to use an autoencoder, which is an unsupervised machine learning algorithm, as a classifier. Are you limited to autoencoder? because other methods (supervised) may be more beneficial here.

Comment: The reason why I am using an unsupervised algorithm is that I do not have enough anomaly samples to train a supervised algorithm.